# org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMTextImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement

Tags: java, xml, axiom

I'm trying to do the following.

```
OMElement soapEnvelope = new StAXOMBuilder(soapEnvelopXMLFilePath).getDocumentElement();
OMElement firstElement = soapEnvelope.getFirstElement().getFirstElement();
```

Then i iterate through the child elements of the firstElement like this.

```
Iterator<OMElement> items = firstElement.getChildren();
while (items.hasNext()) {
    OMElement element = items.next();
    // ....do some processing here...
}
```

But when i try to execute this following class cast exception occurs.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMTextImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement
```

The error occurs when `items.next()` is assigned to element `OMElement` object.

Any idea why i'm getting this exception? I can't figure out any mismatch.

These are the contents of my sample xml file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <ns:MONITOR xmlns:ns="http://try.example.com">
                <ns:HOSTS>
                    <ns:HOST NAME="node1">
                        <ns:METRIC NAME="metric1" VALUE="1123"/>
                        <ns:METRIC NAME="metric3" VALUE="456"/>
                        <ns:METRIC NAME="metric2" VALUE="789"/>
                    </ns:HOST>
                    <ns:HOST NAME="node2">
                        <ns:METRIC NAME="metric1" VALUE="147"/>
                        <ns:METRIC NAME="metric3" VALUE="258"/>
                        <ns:METRIC NAME="metric2" VALUE="369"/>
                    </ns:HOST>
                </ns:HOSTS>
                <ns:HOSTS>
                    <ns:HOST NAME="node3">
                        <ns:METRIC NAME="metric1" VALUE="236"/>
                        <ns:METRIC NAME="metric3" VALUE="159"/>
                        <ns:METRIC NAME="metric2" VALUE="478"/>
                    </ns:HOST>
                </ns:HOSTS>
            </ns:MONITOR>
        </soapenv:Body>
```

Thanks.

Comment: post your sample input xml

Comment: Have you tried it? `OMElement element = (OMElement)items.next();`

Comment: @Naren I've added the sample input xml.

Comment: @ArifKhan Thanks. I've tried that already. That casting is redundant and it doesn't work either. I believe this is something wrong deep within.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `getChildElements` instead of `getChildren`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Such a simple yet accurate answer. It works! :)

Answer (score 2):

Not every node is an element. You should cast children to OMNode and check, if they are elements,  Whitespaces count as text nodes

Comment: I think what you've said is correct. All the child nodes were not seen as elements which triggered the issue. Using @Andreas's suggestion which ensures only elements are taken, solves the issue. Thanks!